# How to add additional css to wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I checked my blog on tablets and netbooks and it looked a bit bad, so I made an extra css and added to header.php in between :

```
<head>
<link media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css">
</head>
```

But nothing happens. How to add an extra .css to make this work ?

Also tried to add this function to themes functions.php, but blog crashes.

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style', 'get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/tablet.css',false,'1.1','all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)');
```

What should I add in 'template_url' and what is the simpliest way of achieving my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just add media queries into the existing CSS sheet?

Comment: Andrew, how to add this condition (,'all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)');) to simple media query inside an existing css?

Comment: Why no include it in the header.php? like: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?/your_css_file/css />"`

Comment: eveevans, what to add in the 'template_url' brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add the code below into the bottom of your stylesheet and apply the styles that you want for those specifications in there. That's for an exact size though.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
  Your styles go in here
}
```

The code below this will target a `max-width` of 768px or a `min-width` of 481px.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), (min-width: 481px) {
  Your styles go in here
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you targeting and testing in?

Comment: im targeting firefox and chrome and opera. If I open my blog on a normal pc or notebook its fine, netbooks or tablets - crappy.

Comment: lets say I have a custom.css with main css conditions and I want to include into it a conditional css like this: @media all and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
  #navigation ul.rss li.sub-rss a {
    background: url("images/ico-social-rss.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 45px 38px 40px 0;
 position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}}

Comment: For any new styles you'd want to apply, you would need to make sure to reset any previous styles. Example: you have `body { background:#FFFFFF; width:500px;}` in your regular styling but on the other sizes you want it to be 200px. It would be `body {width:200px;}, but the background would still be white because everything cascades down.

Comment: solved, I was targeting a bit different resolution, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/css/file.css">
```

Add it to you template `header.php` file, after `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and **after** your **last stylesheet**.

If this fails add it just before the `</head>` tag.

Also make sur your the path to your stylesheet is correct, if your not sure use the full path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.site.com/path/file.css">
```

Hope it helps